# Why does the other list change as well?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have already solved problem 5 of Project Euler (What is the smallest positive number that is evenly divisible (with no remainder) by all of the numbers from 1 to 20?), but I want to find a faster way (currently 0.000109195709229 seconds).

I tried a dynamic approach, but when I run the code below (it is just the first part) I don't understand why *d[var][counter]* gets +1 if I explicitly wrote **d[i][counter] += 1**.

```
n = 20
d = {1:[0,1] + [0]*19}  #a dictionary that assigns to each number a list of its prime factorization
for i in xrange(2,3):   #I changed n+1 with 3 for simplicity
    var = i
    counter = 2
    notDone = True
    while notDone:
        if var % counter == 0:
            var /= counter
            print var, d[var]
            d[i] = d[var]           #i has the same prime factorization of var ...
            print var, d[var]
            d[i][counter] += 1      #... except for 1 number (counter)
            print var, d[var]        #wtf?
            notDone = False
        else:
            counter += 2 if counter != 2 else 1
```

This is the outcome:

```
1 [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
1 [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
1 [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

why does this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the line

```
d[i] = d[var]
```

the variable `d[i]` will hold the same list object as `d[var]`, as lists are *mutable*.

Instead you need a *copy* of `d[var]`, that you can get e.g. by

```
d[i] = d[var][:]
```